# Java code not running to next intent, but works when debugging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if someone could give a hand! I'm running a class as a step in an algorithm for a project, and when i debug pass the class thats giving me problems, it works fine.

But when I run it normally, it goes into an internal loop and stops at the class, and keeps going till I manually stop it.

I am calling from Firebase. The class calls this, and that's where my problem is. But continues on through the intent when I am debugging.

```
public void mySteps(){

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final String product = i.getStringExtra("itemRef");

    myRef.child("day_activities").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String mSteps = (String) snapshot.getValue();
                // changing string to integer to compare values
                int iSteps = Integer.parseInt(mSteps);

                if(iSteps < mySteps){
                    //if the number is less than the recommended amount, changes to this class in
                    //Section1_1 folder
                    Intent intent = new Intent (Steps_Sec_1.this, Sec1_Steps_Sleep.class);
                    intent.putExtra("itemRef", product);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    //If the number is more than the recommended amount, changes to this class in
                    //section_2 folder
                    Intent secondintent = new Intent(Steps_Sec_1.this, Sec2_Steps_Sleep.class);
                    secondintent.putExtra("itemRef", product);
                    startActivity(secondintent);
                }    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Appreciate any help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code is a very bad practice when it comes to loops. This is not a `Firebase` problem nor an `Android` problem is problem regarding the way you loop. What you are actually doing, you are starting a new activity for each iteration of your loop that satisfies or not that condition. So let's assume you have 100 items that satisfy the condition: `iSteps < mySteps`, it means that you starting 100 new activities for each item. That's why your app crashes.

To solve this, display those items in a ListView or even better to a RecyclerView and `setOnClickListener` on the item view and open the corresponding activity.